# Reduce font-size on scroll

Tags: jquery

I have set `font-size: 128px` in CSS. How can I reduce it to `80px` on scroll? The issue I have is the `font-size` reduces until `0` and disappears.

```js
// Static variables - That do not change while scrolling
var header = $("header"),
  headerHeight = header.height(), // Get height of header
  logo = $(".logo"), // Get the logo
  logoHeight = logo.height(), // Get logo height
  fs = logo.css("font-size"),
  scrollTo = 120, // Animation until scrolled to this point
  win = $(window);

$("#main").css("margin-top", win.height());
console.log(fs);

// Scroll function
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  // Dynamic variables - That do change while scrolling
  var yPos = $(this).scrollTop(), // Get the scroll Y-position
    yPer = yPos / scrollTo; // Calculate percenage of scroll

    // If percentage is over 100, set to 100
    if (yPer > 1) {
      yPer = 1;
  }
  // Dynamic variables for the elements
  var logoPos = -1 * (yPer * 50) + 50, // Calculate position of logo (starting from 50%)
    logoSize = headerHeight * yPer - logoHeight * yPer + logoHeight, // Calculate new size height for logo
    headerPos = yPer * headerHeight - headerHeight, // Calculate position of header (starting from minus the height of itself)
  fonts = fs / yPos;

  // Change the top, left, transform and height of the logo
  logo.css({
    top: logoPos + 5 + "%",
    transform: "translate3d(-50%,-" + logoPos + "%,0)",
    fontSize: logoSize,
    height: logoSize
    // left: logoPos + "%",
    // transform: "translate3d(-" + logoPos + "%,-" + logoPos + "%,0)",
  });
  // Change the transform and opacity of the header
  $("header").css({
    //transform: "translate3d(0," + headerPos + "px,0)",
    top: headerPos,
    opacity: yPer
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stf5war1/)**

Comment: Please post whole code.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a `Math.min()` call in the calculation. It's hard to say for certain without seeing a working example.

Comment: @Tanmay, check update question.

Comment: and what's wrong in your jsFiddle?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, check JSFiddle.

Comment: can you be specific?

Comment: @faisaljanjua the fiddle already works as you're asking...?

Comment: You might like to add `img { transition: all 100ms linear; }` to your css, but otherwise, as above, the fiddle appears to be working fine.

Comment: yes, Rory , check the link in ncognito mode.

Comment: the incognito mode should help to...? Sorry, but what browser do you use?

Comment: @freedomn-m, I am using `<a class="logo">I WANT</a>` instead of image. so once I scroll down, the `font-size` reach to `0` and hide the logo, what I am looking, logo will not reduce once its reach `80px`

Comment: Ah, so you're saying your **fiddle has nothing to do with what you want** (as the fiddle uses an image).  Helpful.  Maybe you could update the question to show a working example in a snippet.  Then you'll (very) quickly get some answers.

Comment: From close vote: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Save coming back to this later:  `logoSize = Math.max(80, headerHeight * yPer - logoHeight * yPer + logoHeight)`